# Char array will not print as string to console

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a relatively simple bit of C code - takes in a file *dict.txt* of words (one word per line, all alphabetic letters and lower case).

The goal is to "load" each word into an array called word, print that word, and then repeat until EOF.

Currently, `printf("%s\n", ptr)` prints a blank line to console, rather then a string - as intended. **Why is this and how can I fix?**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

int main(void) {

// open given dictionary
FILE* dict;
dict = fopen("dict.txt", "r");

char word[46];
int index = 0; // to navigate word array
char *ptr = word;

// start loading words
for (int c = fgetc(dict); c != EOF; c = fgetc(dict))
{
    // allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
    if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
    {
        // append character to word
        word[index] = c-97;

        index++;

    } // we must have found a whole word
    else if (index > 0)
    {
        // terminate current word
        word[index] = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", ptr);

        // prepare for next word
        index = 0;
    }

}

// check whether there was an error
if (ferror(dict))
{
    fclose(dict);
    printf("Error reading.\n");
    return 1;
}



// close text
fclose(dict);

return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Moved `ferror()` call to after loop to avoid NULL error.

Comment: Please read the documentation for every function you've used. Calling `ferror()` right after `fopen()` is potentially *undefined behavior*, you can be passing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Good call out. Edited.

Comment: How is `index` going to get to one?

Comment: I say this is a simple typo, unlikely to help anyone else. Do not subtract `97` or the ascii code of `'a'` from `c` if you intend to print the string as ASCII characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant,

```
word[index] = c;
```

you don't need to perform any calculations, specially because `isalpha()` ensures that `c` is a ascii character.

And also fix this

- If `fopen()` fails it returns a `NULL` pointer, so `ferror()` would be called with a `NULL` pointer as parameter and that is **undefined behavior**, instead check that `dict != NULL`.